# LogStash - parsing logs

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse my log files. It was working however there is a new requirement and I need new field from the parsed logs.
Logs are more or less:

```
|2018-02-01 13:48:00.882|[v2.8.0.0]|DEBUG|[EndpointFirst] |Session activated (documentId: 508, workflow id: 1)|
|2018-02-01 13:48:00.901|[v2.8.0.0]|INFO|[Custom.EndpointSecond [Document 508]]|Firing event 'DocumentReceived' on state machine with current state 'Initial' and event argument 'CustomArgument'.|
```

My grok filter:

```
(?<my_timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp})\s*(?<my_version>\[v.{7}])s*(?<my_severity>\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel})\s*(?<my_endpoint>\[.{1,}])\s*(?<my_message>%{DATA:message})
```

Now I got the following fields (result from test grok patterns):

```
MATCHED
my_version  [v2.8.0.0]
my_timestamp    2018-02-01·13:48:00.901
timestamp   2018-02-01·13:48:00.901
my_endpoint [Custom.EndpointSecond·[Document·508]]
my_message  
my_severity ⇥INFO
message 
loglevel    INFO
after match:    Firing event 'DocumentReceived' on state machine with current state 'Initial' and event argument 'CustomArgument'.
```

What I want to achieve?

- I would like to have new field  which should be parsed
  from [Custom.EndpointSecond·[Document·508]] (if there is no log with
  [Document x] then this field should be empty.
- I would like to have message populated with the string which starts
  after  field.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<my_timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp})\s*\|\s*(?<my_version>\[v.{7}])\s*\|\s*(?<my_severity>%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel})\s*\|\s*(?<my_endpoint>\[.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?])\s*\|\s*(?<my_message>%{GREEDYDATA:message})
```

Note the `\s*\|\s*` (matchging a `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces) instead of just `\s*` (since you have the pipes in the string), `\[.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?]` to match an optional `[...]` substring inside `my_endpoint` data and `%{GREEDYDATA:message}` (= `.*`) used instead of `%{DATA:message}` (= `.*?`).

**`\[.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?]` Details**

- `\[` - a `[`
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?` - an optional capturing group "new_field": `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `]`, and then `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. I took your script but it doesn't work yet. Let me analyse that and I will get back to you.

Comment: @Piotr, I tested the regex at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/, and it showed all the fields correctly. I do not add the screen since there are too many fields that do not fit the screen.

Comment: ok, I can see what's the problem. When I added the input here in this topic, "|" character was added automatically instead of whitespaces. I will try to handle this. I will not edit my question because your answer is correct

Comment: @PiotrPtak: Then just replace `\s*\|\s*` with `\s*` or `\s+` (if whitespace is always present between fields).

Comment: One more thing Wiktor, how to change the script in order to do the following: Inside  <my_endpoint> field I just want to have something like Custom.EndpointSecond - meaning I want to get rid of the text [Document X]

Comment: @PiotrPtak There, `(?<my_endpoint>\[.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?])` wraps the whole `[...]` substring. You need to put the first `\[` and last `]` outside the grouping construct: `\[(?<my_endpoint>.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?)]`, but if the whole field is optional, you will have to use an optional non-capturing group - `(?:\|\s*\[(?<my_endpoint>.*?(?<new_field>\[[^\]]*])?)])?`